# error: hash function must be invocable with an argument of key type

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap

I'm using a custom hash function with `unordered_map`, but I get this error:

```
error: static assertion failed: hash function must be invocable with an argument of key type
```

It works fine when I use the default hash function of `unordered_multimap`.

My code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Hasher {
public:
    size_t operator() (string const& key) const {
        size_t hash = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < key.size(); i++) {
            hash += key[i] % 7;
        }
        return hash;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    unordered_multimap<int, int, Hasher, equal_to<int>> hashmap;

    hashmap.insert(make_pair(1, 11));
    hashmap.insert(make_pair(1, 21));
    hashmap.insert(make_pair(2, 12));
    hashmap.insert(make_pair(3, 13));

    auto range = hashmap.equal_range(1); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error message into the question body? Without modifications and including any informational notes.

Comment: After removing the include, and the unused implementation of the `Hasher1` class, the rest of the code compiles without any errors, whatsoever, including the line with the alleged compilation error, by gcc 8.1. This is either not the actual code that fails to compile, or your question is unclear. Your question fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's help center. You need to edit your quesiton, and show the actual code that anyone can use to reproduce your compilation error.

Comment: Are you sure you’re compiling it with c++11?

Comment: What do you mean by "the unused implementation of the Hasher1"?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\unordered_map.h:1458:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
hashjoin.cpp:36:43: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
         hashmap.insert(make_pair(Ra[i], i));
                                           ^
hashjoin.cpp:42:30: error: 'class std::unordered_multimap<int, int, Hasher, std::equal_to<int> >' has no member named 'equal_range'
         auto range = hashmap.equal_range(Sb[i]);
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~`

Comment: Please *edit your question* to include the complete error output (the one in the comment still doesn't look complete). That will make it much easier to format (just paste it all, select it all and format as code by pressing the `{}` button in the toolbar).

Comment: I meant the `Hasher` class. Please point to the line in the shown code which actually uses the `Hasher` class after it's declared. There isn't one. And the class definition uses functions that are not declared anywhere, plus it includes a header file that's not shown. Once again: your question fails to meet the requirements of a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], and you are unlikely to get an answer because without a [mcve] your question is logically unanswerable. Nobody can tell you why you get a compilation error from some other code, other than what's shown here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I use it here: `unordered_multimap<int, int, Hasher, equal_to<int>> hashmap;
`

Comment: Where is "here"?. There's no such line in the shown code. Once again: have you read stackoverflow.com [help] article about preparing a [mcve], and if not, why not?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik line 24

Comment: If you can't figure it out yourself through the error messages, then perhaps do a little bit of [rubber-duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)? Explain to your "rubber duck" what `hashmap` is. Then explain to it what `Hasher` is, especially the `operator()` function. There are some... inconsistencies there that is easier to find when you try to explain it to your rubber duck.

Comment: You edited the question, it was originally `unordered_multimap<int, int> hashmap;`. Even after that edit, your question still fails to meet the requirements of a [mcve], and it cannot be answered, until it does.

Comment: Yeah, I edited seconds later I posted

Comment: I can post the implementation of hash_any function so you can reproduce the error, if it helps.

Comment: No, don't "post the implementation of hash_any", post a [mcve]. If you don't bother to take the minimum of effort to read stackoverflow.com's [help], that explains how to prepare [mcve], even after you were asked several times to do that, then why should anyone help you?

Comment: Now with the proper MCVE, please take some time to read the full and complete error output you get. The error is *not* with the `equal_range` function. You can even remove that call and still get errors.

Comment: You get a much better error message from GCC 8: `error: static assertion failed: hash function must be invocable with an argument of key type`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using mismatched types in the key of `unordered_map` and `operator()` in `Hasher`.

You code should be (please note the comments inline):

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Hasher {
public:
    size_t operator() (string const& key) const {     // the parameter type should be the same as the type of key of unordered_map
        size_t hash = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < key.size(); i++) {
            hash += key[i] % 7;
        }
        return hash;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    unordered_multimap<std::string, int, Hasher, equal_to<std::string>> hashmap;  // key should be string type

    hashmap.insert(make_pair("1", 11));   // key should be string type
    hashmap.insert(make_pair("1", 21));
    hashmap.insert(make_pair("2", 12));
    hashmap.insert(make_pair("3", 13));

    auto range = hashmap.equal_range("1");    // equal_range's parameter should be the same type as key

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And when it is a class with only public members, it could be a `struct`.